# Properties of a binary operator; trouble understanding question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Take a look at the operator $\#$, defined as follows:
>   $$\#:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
>   $$x\mathbin{\#} y = x + 3y$$
>
> (a.) Is the operator $\#$ commutative? Explain.
>
> (b.) Is the operator $\#$ associative? Explain.
>
> (c.) Does the operator $\#$ have an identity e? Explain.
>
> (d.) Can you find two integers $a$ and $b$ that commute for $\#$? Explain.

I don't understand $x \mathbin{\#} y = x + 3y$. Could someone further explain it to me what it mean? Thanks.

Comment: That's only a definition of the operator $\#$.

Comment: Would you find it easier to understand if the exercise read: "The function $f:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ is defined as $f(x,y)=x+3y$. Is $f$ commutative?" and so forth?

Comment: ah thanks, Henning I like your version alot more makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}&(1)\;\;x\#y=x+3y=y+3x=y\#x\;?\\{}\\
&(2)\;\;x\#(y\#z)=(x\#y)\#z \;?\iff x+3(y\#z)=(x\#y)+3z\;?...\\{}\\&(3)\;\;\exists\,e\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;\forall\;x\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;x\#e=x+3e=x\;?\\{}\\
&(4)\;\;\text{Check (1) carefully}\end{align*}$$

Comment: There's been some confused editing of the question, but what the OP intended to ask doesn't really seem to be at this stage, but with understanding the first part of the exercise that defines $\#$ in the first place.

Comment: The identity $e$ must be commutative, so we need to add $x\#e=e\#x=x$. In other case we must says that an identity doesnt exist for $\#$.

Comment: uhm only wanted the question to be simplified, so I could understand it easier and comprehend it to my own way of thinking. But anyways, thanks for the hints :)