# I don't understand the meaning of commute and i can't find any info about it

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Might be duplicate I don't know but [Properties of a binary operator; trouble understanding question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916548/properties-of-a-binary-operator-trouble-understanding-question)

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{c}
            \star : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\\
            x \star y = x + 3y
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}

(d.) Can you find two integers a and b that commute for $\star$? Explain.

Comment: To say that operation $\text {op}$ is *commutative* means that $x \text { op } y = y \text { op } x$, for every $x,y$ on which the operation is defined.

Comment: Applied to you example, this amounts to proving/disproving that $x +3y=y+3x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two integers $a$ and $b$ commute under (or for) $\star$ if $a\star b=b\star a$.

So we are looking for integers $a,b$ such that
$$
a+3b = b+3a.
$$

Comment: tyty i understand now

Comment: One more question, can $a$ and $b$ have the same value ($a=b$) or do they need to have different values

Comment: Under any operation two equal things will always commute, since $a\star a = a\star a$ regardless of the definition of $\star$. You'd have to ask the author of the original question wether that answer was "allowed" though. It's certainly a more interesting question to ask for two different integers commuting under $\star$, and then the answer would be: there are none.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation $\star$ commutes if $a \star b = b \star a$. An example of an operation that does not commute would be a matrix multiplication since if $A$ and $B$ are matrices, it is possible that $A \cdot B \neq B \cdot A$, thus the $\cdot$ operation is not commutative.