# Does the operator $\star$ have a identity e?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question (c) on this [Properties of a binary operator; trouble understanding question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916548/properties-of-a-binary-operator-trouble-understanding-question)

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{c}
            \star : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\\
            x \star y = x + 3y
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}

Does the operator $\star$ have a identity e? Explain.

I know that $\star$ is not commutative and not associative.

I Have come up with that the left identity is $-2y$ and the right identity is $0$. Is this correct or do the operator not have a identity?

If $-2y$ and $0$ is correct, can my explanation be how i got to those answers or do i need to elaborate some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What integer exactly is "$-2y$?" A left identity $x$ to be a *single* number which works for *all* $y$s; if no such $x$ exists then there is no left identity after all.

(What you *have* shown is the following: for every $y$ there is some "left-inverse-**specifically-for**-that-$y$." But that's a very different thing, and indeed not something I believe has a specific name.)

Meanwhile, you are correct that the integer $0$ is a right identity for $\star$: we have for each $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ that $$x\star 0=x+3\cdot 0=x.$$ But note how crucial it is that this single number $0$ works for **every** $x$.

Comment: Does the operator $\star$ have a unit element e? is this the same as does the operator $\star$ have a identity e? If it do, could say that the right side got $0$ as identity and the left side does not have one.

Comment: @needHelp It is once you understand the answer. A unit has to be both a left identity and a right identity. Go back to your claim about left identities; is there, in fact, a left identity?

Comment: Yes, that's right: there is no left identity (do you see how to prove that?), and so a fortiori no identity.

Comment: Sorry if you already answered this. Unit element e and identity e is not the same?

Comment: @needHelp Yes, those are the same. (Most of the time, anyways: in ring theory, "unit" is *also* used to refer to elements which have multiplicative inverses - so in a field, every nonzero element is a unit in this sense. This is why it's better to use the word "identity.")